# SQL SERVER 2005 SETTINGS

Tags: sql-server

I an new in SQL SERVER, I already install it in my laptop, but now facing problem of 
1. how to connect it to putty (what is ip address and other settings)
2. how to connect it to my preinstall oracle 10g database

Comment: I'm not sure that an oracle database is compatible with microsoft slq-server. Also the use putty to connect to sql-server is quite unusal. Why don't you install "SQL Server Management Studio" instead?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You should use SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Will you please tell me where I can find "SQL Server Management Studio"

Comment: @SQLPLSQL http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14630